# Control iOS app version with webservices

Tags: ios, web-services, version-control

I want to know if there's any trouble in creating a version control on my iOS app, because I'm going to make some huge upgrades in my webservices code and don't want that any user try to access the old version and the app crashes or don't work properly.

My idea is to create a service that capture the app version and than, if its an old version, the user can't access the app until the new version is installed.

I know that some android apps do this, but I didn't find any iOS app with this control.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app has a version, and you're writing the web service, so I don't see why you couldn't have your web service check the version and respond with a message that tells the app to show a message asking the user to upgrade.

That said, it would be much, much nicer for your users if you design the web service so that it detects the app version and then provides appropriate functionality for whichever version the user has. You might not want to continue support for the older version forever, but your users would probably appreciate having some time to upgrade when *they* choose to rather than when your app forces them to.